# Photoshop slow when using multiple displays

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

I'm using two different external monitors on my laptop. When I have it on one it's fine, if I use it on the other one, photoshop slows down to almost unusable.

Main difference between monitors is that one is using HDMI and the other is using VGA(the slow one)

any ideas how to speed it up?

Win7, PS5

Comment: Are they both running at the same resolution?

Comment: both running on HD - 1920x1080

Comment: Are you sure? It seems strange to have a VGA connected monitor that runs at 1920x1080? :-/

Comment: it's the dell U2311H http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/Monitors_Flat_Panel_Widescreen/productdetail.aspx?c=ca&l=en&s=dhs&cs=cadhs1&sku=320-9270&~ck=bncat&~bk=gr:CategoryRec_default,g:RecentPopular,rk:

Comment: I've seen many HD monitors support VGA, on some it creates some artifacting and looks a bit less crisp(not quite blurry though)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's very strange that it should be slow with one monitor, but quicker with another... Going on a limb, but, monitor drivers? :-/